# Blade::render a string that contains multiple @include statements doesnt work for included templates that use @extend

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

In my blade template, I use:

```
<div class="entity-content">{!! Blade::render($project->content, compact('project')) !!}</div>
```

`$project->content` is:

```
<div class="contact-list">
@include('content.contacts.jane-doe')
@include('content.contacts.john-doe')
@include('content.contacts.hardcoded')
</div>
```

jane-doe.blade.php:

```
@extends('content.contacts.contact')

@section('content')
    Jane Doe
@endsection
```

john-doe.blade.php:

```
@extends('content.contacts.contact')

@section('content')
    John Doe
@endsection
```

hardcoded.blade.php:

```
Hardcoded
```

The output of the `Blade::render` is:

Jane Doe
Jane Doe
Hardcoded

So, for every included blade template that uses `@extend`, the first included/ extended result is used for all the following `@include` statements aswell. Is this a bug? How can I correctly include templates that extend? `deleteCachedView: true` didnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why you so often find the answer yourself right after asking, not in the research before, but `@overwrite` to the rescue:

In each blade file, that uses `@extends`, replace `endSection` with `@overwrite`:

```
@extends('content.contacts.contact')

@section('content')
    Jane Doe
@overwrite
```

I think its a bit unintuitive but it works for me. [More](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1058).